# How to use jQuery to submit a form and then reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible.

I have Page-A that has Form-Foo with an action to Bar in a new window.

Upon clicking submit, I'd like the form to submit AND Page-A to reload.

So far I can only get one or the other to work...any pointers would be appreciated.

In addition to DudeSolutions solution...I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').submit(function() {
        $.post('bar.asp', $(#foo).serialize(), function(data) {

                window.location.reload();

        });

    });
});
```

Same results...I can get the form to submit and a new tab opens...but Page-A does not reload.

Comment: would certainly help if you outlined what you have tried, so others know what isn't working for you

Comment: I think AJAX is the solution to your problem.

Comment: What about to point your action to a javascript function where you do your form submit and `setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you intend to submit the form and reload the page, that would be the default behaviour, and only the url in the action attribute is incorrect. If so just change the URL, no need for ajax if a new pageload is intended anyway :

```
$(function() {
    $('#Form-Foo').attr('action', 'Page-A url');
});
```

or:

```
$(function() {
    $('#foo').on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          setTimeout(function() {
               window.location.reload();
          },0);
          this.submit();
    });
});
```

Just queueing the reload should be enough to wait until after the form is sent to reload the page, but as most browsers stop the timeout when you leave the browser tab, it won't really reload until you go back to that tab, but that should be unnoticeable.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an idea:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#my_form").submit(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/path/to/post/handler/",
        data: $("#my_form").serializeArray(),
        success: function() {
    top.reload();
        }
        });
    return false;
});</script>
```

Comment: That's essentially what I've been trying. The form submits, new page opens with intended results but Page-A does not reload.